# Task Host is Stopping Background Task

Tags: windows-10

When I go to shut down, I get Task Host is Stopping Background Task followed by, Microsoft/Windows/DeviceDirectoryClient/RegisteredUserDevice.  I have no idea what this is referring to.

Answer (score 0):

That's a windows program. Don't worry about it being a virus damaging your system.

When you shut down your system, Task Host ensues that programs previously running were closed properly to avoid data and program corruption.

Read this to know it well:

Fix: Task Host Window Prevents Shut Down in Windows 8/10

https://appuals.com/solved-task-host-window-prevents-shut-down-in-windows-810/

[Task Host Window Prevents Windows Shutdown](https://superuser.com/questions/1241868/task-host-window-prevents-windows-shutdown?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)